How to check endpoint on a specific path in prometheus using blackbox exporter
I am trying to check service running on port 9001/healthcheck on each of my ec2 instances in the account and want to validate it using blackbox_exporter in prometheus. For this I created this prometheus.yml:
- job_name: 'blackbox'
  metrics_path: /probe
  params:
    module: [http_9001_healthcheck]
  ec2_sd_configs:
  - region: eu-central-1
    port: 9001         
    filters:
      - name: "tag:Account"
        values:
          - abc
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      target_label: __param_target
    - source_labels: [__param_target]
      target_label: instance
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: localhost:9115

This is my blackbox.yml:
modules:
  http_9001_healthcheckk:
    prober: http
    timeout: 15s
    http:
      method: GET
      valid_http_versions:
        - HTTP/1.1
        - HTTP/2.0
      fail_if_not_ssl: false
      valid_status_codes: [200]
      no_follow_redirects: false
      ip_protocol_fallback: false
      preferred_ip_protocol: ip4

This is checking application on 9001 only. How I can add /healthcheck as well in this?

You can append /healthcheck to parameter target by adding replacement: $1/healthcheck to first relabel_config block.

But I believe this question should be closed as off-topic and moved to some other site of network.

@markalex how it is off topic?

This is not related to development. This is a question about configuration of Prometheus and/or blackbox exporter, non of which is a tool commonly used by programmers. Consider [help/on-topic] and [devops.se]

I have seen lots of prometheus issues on Stackoverflow. Surprised to know that DEvops related issues are not for Programmer? Is this forum not for Devops?

Prometheus questions are not necessarily off-topic: questions about promQL and instrumentation of applications are clearly development related. Regarding DevOps: Ops part is (generally) off-topic. Some of it is in gray zone, and doesn't belong to any site of the network, and thus is often left where is asked. Some of it was answered before creation of devops.se, and is left here. And some, like k8s questions, is often left here because number of those who ask and answer is significantly bigger than those who curates and cares.

I suggest stopping this discussion here. If you feel I'm wrong, or want tot bring this to attention of broader community, feel free to ask a dedicated question on [meta]

One last thing: Stack Overflow is not a forum. Nor it was intended to be. Same for other sites of network. Please mark all previous meta comments by me as No longer needed, once you've read them. TIA
